Date/Element range index on MM-DD-YYYY format in MarkLogic
Have user data with timestamp in the below format and stored as string.
MM-DD-YYYYThh:mm:ss
Sample:
{
  "Name":"myname",
  "created":"12-17-2014T13:40:07"
}

I want to find all the documents created after a given timestamp. Element Range index with scalar type as date time does not work.
My basic requirement is to find all the documents created after the given time.
Would appreciate any help to meet the requirements

You could create a TDE that parses that dateTime value and indexes it as xs:dateTime
Below is an example of how to do that:
'use strict'
const tde = require("/MarkLogic/tde.xqy");
const createdTDE = 
  {
    "template": {
      "context": "/created",
      "vars":[
        {
          "name":"myDateTime",
          "val":"xdmp:parse-dateTime('[M01]-[D01]-[Y0001]T[h01]:[m01]:[s01]', .)"
        }
      ],
      "rows": [
        {
          "schemaName": "test",
          "viewName": "created",
          "columns": [
            {
              "name": "created",
              "scalarType": "dateTime",
              "val": "$myDateTime"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
tde.templateInsert(
  "/test/createdTDE.json" ,
  createdTDE,
  xdmp.defaultPermissions(),
  ["TDE"]
)

Once you have the TDE in place, you can use it to select where created is greater or less than.
cts.search(
  cts.columnRangeQuery("test", "created", "created", xs.dateTime('2014-12-17T13:40:07'), ">"), 
  "unfiltered"
) 


As @rjrudin already mentioned, change the source data to match an xs:date-time format.  If the source data cannot be changed, then there are a few alternatives:

Brute force:

Iterate over documents, dynamically check.  Not very efficient and not scalable.


Metadata:

Use a script to farm the data and add it as a metadata value to the
document in the proper format.
Then add a field to the metadata
Then add a range index
Use a range query


Triple - a persisted functional index:

benefits from the following characteristics of a triple:

Linked to document fragment (in all recent versions of MarkLogic)
Already stored as a range index


Create a TDE template that transforms the date the the appropriate format
Store this as the object of a triple
Use cts.tripleRangeQuery() for search or op.fromSparql()/op.fromTriples() if using Optic API


Same as (3) - but create a view with a column. Then use via Optic, SQL or cts.columnRangeQuery()


Thank a lot Mads, David and @rjrudin for your input.

You need to change the order of the year/month/date - try the following in qconsole to see what's an accepted dateTime:
xs.dateTime("2024-12-17T13:40:07")


Problem is I can't change the source data
